# upgrading ipad mini device A1455 model

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8

I have ipad mini devices with iOS 6 and iOS 7. I need to upgrade them to iOS 8. but apple software update directly upgrades to iOS 9.2.1. How do I upgrade to iOS 8?

Comment: Sorry you can't upgrade it to iOS 8

Comment: vote to close. this is heavily OT for this page

Answer (score 2):

You can download requred ipsw from
 http://www.iphonehacks.com/download-iphone-ios-firmware
or 
http://www.ipswdownloader.com/

And you can install it using itunes

For Mac: OPTION + Click on the “Update” button
For Windows: SHIFT + Click on the ‘Update’ button

I'm not very sure weather now apple allow this or not. But i had done this once. Don't forget to take backup.
cheers..